# Using artisan serve after changing the public folder name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

As with a lot of hosts our public folder is called `public_html`. This is on shared hosting so can't be changed. I've changed the `public` folder to `public_html` to reflect this, but when I do `artisan serve` stops working. Every time I try to start it I get:

```
[ErrorException]
chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2)
```

If I rename the folder back to public then `artisan serve` starts working again.

I've tried [following this post on laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-do-you-set-public-directory-laravel-5#reply-49083), and the user in the post reports artisan works for them, but it made no difference to me. How can I change the folder and have `artisan serve` work?

Comment: FYI, Laravel is unlikely to play nice with many shared hosts.

Comment: @ceejayoz Why is that? I'm about to redevelop our CMS using Laravel so if that's the case it would be a real pain in the ass.

Comment: Depends on the host. Some won't let you properly set the permissions/ACLs on the `storage` directory. I'd test with a minimal app on your preferred host to see if everything works as expected. You could also consider using something like DigitalOcean to get a $5/month VPS.

Comment: Well we use Heart Internet and it seems someone has already written a guide for Laravel with them - http://novate.co.uk/deploy-laravel-5-on-shared-hosting-from-heart-internet/. I think we should be OK.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dipesh's answer is actually a very bad idea - those changes will be blown away anytime you do a Composer install/update/require. **Never directly edit anything in the `vendor` directory.**

Instead, in `bootstrap/app.php`, you should add:

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

right after

```
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__ . '/../')
);
```

See https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-do-you-set-public-directory-laravel-5 for further discussion and alternate ways of doing this in a safe manner.

You could also [extend `Illuminate\Foundation\Application`](http://woodmarks.nl/using-the-public_html-folder-instead-of-public/). This appears to be necessary for the Laravel CLI (anything starting with `php artisan`) to pick it up.

Comment: Thanks for that, but if you noticed I linked that very discussion in my original question. I've already modified `bootstrap/app.php` to no avail. I also set up `/app/Providers/CustomServiceProvider.php` and listed it in `config/app.php` with the other providers as suggested by one of the last posts.

Comment: @Styphon Did you try the last link I added, extending Illuminate\Foundation\Application? I suspect it's necessary as Laravel's CLI seems to need the `publicPath()` function, which you'd need to use the extension technique for. Again, the other answer - directly editing `vendor` - will break on you very quickly.

Comment: I've just tried that now, it works a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately both links in the answer are broken. If you need it to work with `artisan`, check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33652169/1296104

Answer (score -1):

find `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php` this file 
and change on following function

```
/**
 * Get the path to the public / web directory.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function publicPath()
{
    return $this->basePath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'public_html';
}
```

Comment: @Styphon This is actually a very bad idea and will be blown away the next time you use `composer update`, `composer require`, or `composer install`.

Comment: You should not change any code on core files. Chose either way from ceejayoz's post.

Comment: You could easily just extend the core class. Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33652169/1296104